# secure adobe air html/javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, security, air

I would like to develop desktop application with adobe air. but I am worried about html/javascript source code security.

Application has paid media content and I would not like to expose urls.

How can I secure source code?

Comment: url's are going to be exposed anyway; the user can always intercept network calls.  better bet would be encrypted media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't feel like anyone will be able to answer your question, because what you are asking for is not good practice. What you are trying to do is basically [**security through obscurity**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). You are hoping you will be more clever than any malicious users who download your app, and none of them will be able to figure out where you hide the stuff that is executing on their computers.

> The United States National Institute of Standards and Technology
>   (NIST) specifically recommends against security through obscurity in
>   more than one document. Quoting from one, "System security should not
>   depend on the secrecy of the implementation or its components." [-source](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-123/SP800-123.pdf)

No matter what measures you take to obscure a URL, if the site is going to be visited on a computer where the user has physical access, it will be vulnerable.

Depending on what language your server software is written in, you can implement something like [user accounts/roles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control). If you have a question about how to do that, you should give it a fair shot, and post another question if you come up with one.